# Why is there a different result of an method when modified its object with a portable extension and applied an interceptor on the same object too?

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor

Maybe you can give a hint, where to find a solution for this problem.

Currently I discover CDI portable extensions, like the sample shown here [Wrapping an InjectionTarget](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e5239).

This CDI portable extension reads values from properties files and configures fields of a Java object.

Here is a snippet of the extension:

```
public <T> void checkForPropertyFileAnnotation(
        final @Observes ProcessInjectionTarget<T> pit) {

    AnnotatedType<T> at = pit.getAnnotatedType();
    if (!at.isAnnotationPresent(PropertyFile.class)) {
        return;
    }
    // found annotation
    [...load properties...]
    [...assign properties to fields...]
    [...create new wrapped InjectionTarget...]
    pit.setInjectionTarget([created InjectionTarget]);
}
```

Running this extension on an example class does what it should do. But when I apply a, for example LoggingInterceptor like shown here [simple cdi interceptor](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-cdi-interceptor/), the extension seems not working.

The logging interceptor:

```
    @Log @Interceptor
    public class LoggingInterceptor {

        @AroundInvoke 
        public Object log(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ctx.getTarget().getClass().getName());
            logger.info("before");

            Object result = ctx.proceed();

            logger.info("after");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The sample-class looks like:

```
@Named
@Model // to use EL in jsp/jsf
@Log // the interceptor annotation
@PropertyFile("myprops.txt") // the annotation used within the extension
public class MyProperties {
    @Property("version")
    Integer version;

    @Property("appname")
    String appname;

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }
}
```

The content of the result-page:

```
<h:body bgcolor="white">
    #{myProperties.appname} v#{myProperties.version}
</h:body>
```

It's not really true, the extension works, means it injects the appropriate values into the desired fields as I can see in the log-file, but after the interceptor gets applied, the injected values are gone.

Do you have any idea why this can happen? Maybe the extension handles a different instance of the class than the interceptor.

Thanx in advance for your reply!

Comment: Please provide some more info.  What container are you running?

Comment: I'm using TomEE+ 1.6.0

Comment: So what? What more info should I provide, to get in the situation of an lightning hint. The questioning is pretty simple:
I've put two default examples together, each of them work as they are supposed to work (the extension works, the intercepter works), but both together do not work as expected. The extension treats another instance than the intercepter.

Answer (score 0):

You're twiddling fields on a proxy class, and then the getters are getting the values from the underlying instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Both the interceptor and extension work separately, but when used together, the interceptor stops working. This is due to a bug in OpenWebBeans CDI implementation where interceptors are only processed when the injection target is an instance of an OpenWebBeans specific InjectionTargetImpl.

See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OWB-897

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of your link because it might be removed in the (near) future.